# Reordering in Hierarchical category structure

Tags: mysql, hierarchical

I have a category table that use Hierarchical structure with right and left field.

What should I do if I want to reorder two fields and how should I manage left and right field values?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using left and right, you're probably modelling this as a Nested Set. The top answer to [this question about nested sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889527/mysql-move-node-in-nested-set) has a nice method for moving nodes.